# Ошибка компиляции при вызове mciSendString в Windows Forms

Tags: windows, winforms, c++, visual-studio

На нажатие кнопки добавил событие открывания cd-привода

```
mciSendString(L"Set cdaudio door open wait", 0, 0, 0);
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку

> `cd.obj : error LNK2028: ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00000F) "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall mciSendStringW(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int,struct HWND__ *)" (?mciSendStringW@@$$J216YGKPB_WPA_WIPAUHWND__@@@Z) в функции "private: void __clrcall cd::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@cd@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
> 1>cd.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall mciSendStringW(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int,struct HWND__ *)" (?mciSendStringW@@$$J216YGKPB_WPA_WIPAUHWND__@@@Z) в функции "private: void __clrcall cd::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@cd@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)`

Если написать так

```
mciSendString("Set cdaudio door open wait", 0, 0, 0);
```

то ошибка следующая

> `c:\documents and settings\illarion\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\Form1.h(96): error C2664: mciSendStringW: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "const char [27]" в "LPCWSTR"
> 1>          Типы, на которые указывают указатели, не связаны; для преобразования требуется reinterpret_cast, приведение в стиле С или приведение в стиле функции`

Как сделать, чтобы все работало? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вариант

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <string>

// ...

std::wstring command = L"Set cdaudio door open wait";

mciSendString(command.c_str(), NULL, 0, 0);
```

либо вариант

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

[System::Runtime::InteropServices::DllImport("winmm.dll")]
System::Int64 mciSendString(System::String ^command, StringBuilder ^result, long resultLength, int  callback);

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ command = "Set cdaudio door open wait";

    mciSendString(command, nullptr, 0, 0);
    Console::Read();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ура!!!!!!!!!! Спасибо огромное! Я просто добавил 
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")
и все заработало!